# How can I pass cursor as a parameter in an already stored procedure Oracle?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, database-cursor

The procedure looks like this

```
proc.pkg.fcn('parameter1','parameter2','parameter3','parameter4',
             'parameter5','parameter6','parameter7','parameter8').
```

This procedure takes only single inputs in each parameter per execution. I want to be able to send multiple inputs of parameter1 keeping all other parameters constant i.e.

```
proc.pkg.fcn('List/Arrayof(parameter1)','parameter2','parameter3','parameter4',
         'parameter5','parameter6','parameter7','parameter8').
```

**Q1**. How can I use oracle cursor in above scenario to get list of parameter 1 and then pass it as a parameter in above stored procedure to get the values?

**Q2**. If I define a cursor to get list of parameter1 and then pass it as an argument in stored procedure, will I also have to change the code of stored procedure to accept cursor as an argument?

**Q3**. Is there any better alternative to the solution I am thinking to implement ?

I haven't tried this approach yet. At first, I was thinking to apply forLoop over List/Array of parameter1 and then pass parameter1 one by one in stored procedure but that will take a lot of time.

Comment: Oracle's PL/SQL variables are statically typed. You cannot pass an array-like object (or even a cursor, which is totally different datatype) to scalar parameter to make the code "expand" it. You may iterate over the cursor and perform a call on each loop pass or accept array-like input parameters (but need to create `type table of ...` beforehand)

Comment: Q2 - If you change the signature from a string to something else (such as a cursor) then, yes, you are going to have to change the procedure.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use cursors for this? If you want to pass an array then pass an array (which in Oracle are called collections). Unless your array is going to be huge and create memory management issues unless you stream it (and even then you can see whether a pipelined function to generate a collection would work).

Answer (score 1):

If it is strings, then there is a pre-existing collection type SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST which allows ~32000 values to be passed, thus:

```
SQL> create or replace
  2  procedure MYPROC(p1 SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST, p2 varchar2, p3 varchar2) is
  3  begin
  4    for i in 1 .. p1.count
  5    loop
  6      dbms_output.put_line('p1 vals: '||p1(i));
  7    end loop;
  8  end;
  9  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> exec myproc(sys.odcivarchar2list('oneval'),'p2','p3');
p1 vals: oneval

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> exec myproc(sys.odcivarchar2list('two','vals'),'p2','p3');
p1 vals: two
p1 vals: vals

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Check out the ways of dealing with arrays here

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html